# Gulp concatenating javascript files and libraries only execute babel on es6 code

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat

What is the best practice for concatenating javascript files with gulp?
I want to concatenate all my javascript files in one app.js file.
Before that there are several files written in es6 which need to be transpiled with babel. How can I tell a stream that babel should leave out the frameworks?
I use main-bower-files to automate selecting all relavent framework files, with which comes another problem. How can I order all via main-bower-files selected frameworks, so that jquery is always at the beginning of the concatenated file.

Meanwhile I first copy all bower files and es6 files into a directory and then concatenate everything together:

```
    gulp.task('concat', ['babel', 'copy-bower-files'], function() {
        return gulp.src([destPublicLib + '**/jquery.min.js', destPublicLib + '**/*.min.js', destPublicJs + '**/*.js'])
            .pipe(concat('app.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(destPublic));
    });
```

Is there a cleaner way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could benefit to switch from gulp to [webpack](https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto), as webpack can work with babel and other compile-to-js tools .